# How to set active navbar item based on path if pathes starts with the same word in react

Tags: reactjs, react-router

It is needed to set active css property to active navbar item based on path. The problem is that two of the pathes are "/dashboard" and "dashboard/repositories". In a result both of icons for dashboard and dashboard/repositories become active

```
    return (
      <div>
        <Sidebar className='sidebar'>
          <div className={styles['sidebar_logo']}>
            <img src={require('../../../img/logo.svg')} alt='logo'/>
          </div>
          {this.renderMenu()}
        </Sidebar>
      </div>
    )

-----------
  private renderMenu = () => {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        {this.renderMenuItem('/dashboard', 'Dashboard')}
        {this.renderMenuItem('/dashboard/repositories', 'Repositories')}
        {this.renderMenuItem('/collections', 'Collections')}
        {this.renderMenuItem('/user-management', 'User Management')}
        {this.renderMenuItem('/settings', 'Settings')}
        {this.renderMenuItem('/account', 'Account')}
      </React.Fragment>
    )
  }

----------------
  renderMenuItem = (route: string, title: string) => {
    const isActive = this.getActiveRoute(route)
    return (
      <div className={[styles['navLink'], styles[`${isActive && 'navLink_active'}`]].join(' ')}>
        <NavLink to={route}>
          {this.getNavIcon(route, isActive)}
        </NavLink>
      </div>
    )
  }

-----------------
  @action
  private getActiveRoute = ((route: string) => {
    return this.props.location.pathname.includes(route)
  })
```

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you'd use `this.props.location.pathname.includes(route)` over an equality check? Since you seem to be directly comparing 2 routes, would `this.props.location.pathname === route` be more effective? Maybe using something other than `includes` could be a possible solution here.

Comment: yeap, it is possible to use this.props.location.pathname === route, but there is another problem which appears when, for example, our route is /dashboard/repositories/:repo_alias/:definition/analysis. In this case Nav Item with path /dashboard/repositories should be active, but actually none of nav items is active